# Working with azure mobile service in android

Tags: android, android-studio, azure-mobile-services

I am working on a project in which I have to work with Azure Back end, I have inserted data into the table, but don't know how to get its response and where should I use Json parsing .. below is my code .. please guide me about this

```
 mClient.getTable(TodoItem.class).insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<TodoItem>() {
                public void onCompleted(TodoItem entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                    if (exception == null) {
                        // Insert succeeded


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        // Insert failed
                        String msg=exception.getCause().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

For information on using the Android client SDK for Azure Mobile Apps, see the following articles:

- [Create an Android app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started/)
- [Enable offline sync for your Android mobile app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data/)
- [How to use the Android client library for Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library/)

Comment: Thanks , i had a little look on it , also i tried some methods but not able to get Response from it , Do i need to add some response in AZure Table , or by default it return some response...